# reading CSV in Java

Tags: java, csv

[Snap shot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yqvg.png) [Problematic row example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0b5X.png)
I am having trouble reading a csv thanks to rows like the one I've provided that are in the csv file. The word Schr"" is affecting the reader by making it think that the value ends there. How do I work around this? not all rows are like this. It reads fine till it reaches rows like this. I am also using openCSV reader for this.
The parseInteger() fcuntion is just a function I made to help me debug and find the problem.

```
 while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                int id = parseInteger(line.length > 0 ? line[0] : null,0);
                String title = line.length > 1 ? line[1] : null;
                String abstractText = line.length > 2 ? line[2] : null;
                int maths = parseInteger(line.length > 3 ? line[3] : null, 0);
                int physics = parseInteger(line.length > 4 ? line[4] : null, 0);
                int compsc = parseInteger(line.length > 5 ? line[5] : null, 0);
                int stats = parseInteger(line.length > 6 ? line[6] : null, 0);
                int quantbio = parseInteger(line.length > 7 ? line[7] : null, 0);
                int quantfin = parseInteger(line.length > 8 ? line[8] : null, 0);


                articles.add(new Article(title, id, abstractText, maths, physics, compsc, stats, quantbio, quantfin));
```

I tried using making different functions to try to work around it but so far nothings worked.

Comment: Don't post code in an image. The code should be posted formatted with the  question.

Comment: Remove the `\""` from the word `Shrodinger` within the *Alternate text* column. You will find this nonsense in several CSV records. Be sure that you are using **CSVReader** as well.

Comment: The correct spelling is Schrödinger, but it seems that someone thinks it's a good idea to use the string `\"" o` instead of the letter ö. Do a search & replace in the file. Either that, or you are reading with the wrong character encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the backslash and double quotes. CSV is using commas as value separator, so if you need to use a comma in a value, you have to enclose the value in double quotes.
`Value1,Value2,"Value,3",Value4`

If you need to use comma and double quotes, you need to escape it (e.g.):
`Value1,Value2,"Value,\"3\"",Value4`

I think, that the CSV is not valid and the parser is confused from the double quotation with back slash.

You should sanitize your CSV first and use the escape sequence only where it should be used.

In your case, this is not valid:
`val1,Schr\"",val3`

This will work:
`val1,"Schr\"",val3`